# Absolute newbie question: why can't I open my dataset?

Tags: r

I am taking a statistics in public health course in Coursera, and the very [first lesson](https://www.coursera.org/learn/introduction-statistics-data-analysis-public-health/lecture/QWm9d/how-to-load-data-and-run-basic-tabulations-in-r) in R is a simple loading of data tutorial.

I followed the video to a tee but when I input:

```r
g <- read.csv(file="Downloads/cancer data for MOOC 1.csv", header=TRUE, sep=',')
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'Downloads/cancer data for MOOC 1.csv': No such file or directory
```

I tried moving the csv file to different directories but I still get the same error message.